# nodejs route.get to SEND a post request

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

The get to this route works fine.

But how do I take my route.get() and make it do a post?
If the post is written in jquery, or express, or something else I don't care.  Below I just used the jquery as an example.

```
router.get('/', function (req, res, next) {
    var url = 'blabla'
    $.post('anotherBlaBla'
        , { app: url }
    );
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use http client [axios](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios)

**Performing a POST request**

```
 var axios = require('axios');

 axios.post('/user', {
    firstName: 'Fred',
    lastName: 'Flintstone'
 })
 .then(function (response) {
    console.log(response);
 })
 .catch(function (error) {
    console.log(error);
 });
```

Comment: Thanks for the help.  I worked with this until I'm blue in the face.  "TypeError: not a method" meaning axios.post() doesn't exists.  But I can'y find why not.

Comment: And doing this doesn't actually do anything.  `axios(config);`  It doesn't error.  But it also doesn't execute.

Comment: `axios.post()` exists for sure [on npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios#axiosposturl-data-config). The result is a promise. Please don't forget to vote up my answer if it helps.

Comment: I know.  And I can't figure out why the node run-time says it doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

```
const request = require('request');

var url = 'blabla';

request.post(
    url
    , { json: { api: url } }
    , function (err, res, bdy) {
        if (!err && res.statusCode == 200)
            console.log(bdy)
    }
);
```